# Fireplace burner - air mixing valve needed?

Tags: fireplace

Currently in the fireplace there is a gas log lighter burner (a straight pipe with several holes in it), and it has an air mixing valve on the end between it and the natural gas source.  Does anyone know why this is needed?  Looking online it seems related to propane or to getting the flame bluer/hotter.  The context is replacing this small burner with one that outputs more heat (though with safety considerations like maximum BTU in mind) and whether something like this would still be needed.  The replacement burner in mind does not show one being needed.

Comment: Natural gas doesn't ignite unless it has the correct gas/oxygen ratio.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement burner no doubt has one incorporated in its design, not bodged on as a separate part.

Natural gas needs air mixed in to burn correctly. The amount of air .vs. fuel (roughly 10:1) is different than the amount with propane, (roughly 15.6:1) but "none" is not the correct amount for anything that isn't a pathetic excuse for a flame.